# SpriteKit Scene Pause

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to pause the current scene whenever it goes in the background and whenever an iAD is opened.

With my Code, it acts strange, like after the scene unpauses, it runs everything what should be done while it was paused in a second. I recognized this happens most likely if I pause and unease the scene very fast, so I tried to add a `NSTimer`but in the end it didn't work.

Also, it doesn't pause the whole scene.For e.g. I got 2 Nodes, running actions. The first node is paused, but the second doesn't.

**Edit:** Thanks to LearnCocos2D, you can't pause the update: method. Instead of `skView.scene.paused = YES;` you write `skView.paused = YES;`

My Code :

`AppDelegate.m`

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
view.paused = YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(UnpauseGame)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
}

- (void)UnpauseGame
{
SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
view.paused = NO;
}
```

`ViewController.m`

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{

SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.scene.paused = YES;

return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.scene.paused = NO;
}
```

The SpriteNode that doesn't pause in `MyScene.m`

```
-(SKSpriteNode *)createBackground {

Baumstamm = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"BaummitLeiter.png"];
Baumstamm.size = CGSizeMake(280, 570);
Baumstamm.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2);
Baumstamm.zPosition = 2;
Baumstamm.name = BACK_GROUND;

return Baumstamm;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:BACK_GROUND usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y - 5);

if (node.position.y < -(node.frame.size.height + 100))
{
    [node removeFromParent];
}
}];

if (self.currentBackground.position.y < (self.frame.size.height / 2))
{
SKSpriteNode *temp = [self createBackground];
temp.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.currentBackground.position.y + self.currentBackground.frame.size.height);
[self addChild:temp];
self.currentBackground = temp;
}
```

Comment: pausing the scene will not pause the update: method, pause the view instead

Comment: If I tap the Ad now, it works for me, thanks! But in the AppDelegate it pauses the view, not the scene. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For pausing in scenarios like this, I put a conditional in my update method that makes sure the scene isn't paused before it executes everything. That way, you can selectively choose what keeps happening during pause and what doesn't.